# What's the max number of file descriptors on Android?

Tags: android, resources, file-descriptor

We are using Erlang VM to run Couch DB on Android. Recently we have hit a limitation where Erlang complains about exceeding the file descriptors.

The way Erlang calculates maximum file descriptors is here - 
https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/sys/common/erl_poll.c#L2308-L2320

Given the above piece of code, what will max_fds be set to on Android? In our case, it throws error saying file descriptors exceeded 255. Is this such a low number?

Also, is there anyway we can increase this limit so that we get 512 or 1024 max_fds on Android?

**Update:** I have got some additional information. Android has sysconf method and that is returning 256 for max open file descriptors limit. The strange thing is that Android allows a process to open 1024 files. So it seems sysconf is returning a wrong value where the system supports more than this. Is this a bug in Android?

Comment: first i would check why Vm needs so many FDs(seriously, does it need 255 opened files at the same time?) ... then i would try increase the limit ... remeber that there are devices with 1024 max_fds limits for entire device

Comment: @Selvin - These are not only files. It includes sockets, pipes, files etc. I understand we might be expecting too much. However, limit of 255 appears too less actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android (JB as well as Lollypop) definitely seems to return 256 for sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) whereas it actually supports maximum 1024 file descriptors for a process. This looks like a bug to me.

If I am wrong, please update in the comments.

Thanks

Comment: You can try to look in the google code sources to find out what is the "real" settings and if this is indeed a bug.